# Addressing specific namespace elements in XML (RDF) not working

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, rdf

I am trying to extract some information from an rdf-xml-file and have some trouble doing so. The xml looks roughly like this (only the beginning of the file):

```
<searchRetrieveResponse>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <numberOfRecords>528</numberOfRecords>
  <records>
    <record>
      <recordSchema>RDFxml</recordSchema>
      <recordPacking>xml</recordPacking>
      <recordData>
        <rdf:RDF>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="https://d-nb.info/1241327858">
            <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/Document"/>
            <dcterms:medium rdf:resource="http://rdaregistry.info/termList/RDACarrierType/1018"/>
            <rdau:P60049 rdf:resource="http://rdaregistry.info/termList/RDAContentType/1020"/>
            <rdau:P60050 rdf:resource="http://rdaregistry.info/termList/RDAMediaType/1003"/>
            <rdau:P60048 rdf:resource="http://rdaregistry.info/termList/RDACarrierType/1018"/>
            <dc:identifier rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">(DE01)1241327858</dc:identifier>
            <bibo:isbn13 rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">9783347382671</bibo:isbn13>
            <umbel:isLike rdf:resource="https://nbn-resolving.org/urn:nbn:de:101:1-2021091702442180874645"/>
            <foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">https://tredition.de/publish-books/?books/ID164010</foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf>
            <dcterms:language rdf:resource="http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/iso639-2/ger"/>
            <rdau:P60327 rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Judith L. Bestgen, Roberta Altmann</rdau:P60327>
            <dc:title rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Die Fehde der Gezeiten</dc:title>
            <dcterms:creator>
              <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="node1fhgbdto1x1870134">
                <gndo:preferredName rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Bestgen, Judith L.</gndo:preferredName>
              </rdf:Description>
...
```

I am trying to extract the data I want with the following function:

```
def parse_record_rdf(record):
    
    ns = {"xlmns":"http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/", 
          "agrelon":"https://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/agrelon#",
          "bflc":"http://id.loc.gov/ontologies/bflc/",
          "rdau":"http://rdaregistry.info/Elements/u/",
          "dc":"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/",
          "rdau":"http://rdaregistry.info/Elements/u",
          "bibo":"http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/",
          "dbp":"http://dbpedia.org/property/",  
          "dcmitype":"http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/", 
          "dcterms":"http://purl.org/dc/terms/", 
          "dnb_intern":"http://dnb.de/", 
          "dnbt":"https://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/dnb#", 
          "ebu":"http://www.ebu.ch/metadata/ontologies/ebucore/ebucore#", 
          "editeur":"https://ns.editeur.org/thema/", 
          "foaf":"http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/", 
          "gbv":"http://purl.org/ontology/gbv/", 
          "geo":"http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#", 
          "gndo":"https://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/gnd#", 
          "isbd":"http://iflastandards.info/ns/isbd/elements/", 
          "lib":"http://purl.org/library/", 
          "madsrdf":"http://www.loc.gov/mads/rdf/v1#", 
          "marcrole":"http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/relators/",
          "mo":"http://purl.org/ontology/mo/", 
          "owl":"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#", 
          "rdf":"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#", 
          "rdfs":"http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#", 
          "schema":"http://schema.org/", 
          "sf":"http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#", 
          "skos":"http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#", 
          "umbel":"http://umbel.org/umbel#", 
          "v":"http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#", 
          "vivo":"http://vivoweb.org/ontology/core#", 
          "wdrs":"http://www.w3.org/2007/05/powder-s#", 
          "xsd":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"}
    
    xml = etree.fromstring(unicodedata.normalize("NFC", str(record)))
    
    
    #idn
    idn = xml.findall(".//dc:identifier", namespaces=ns)
    try:
        idn = idn[0].text
    except:
        idn = 'N/A' 
        
    
    #creator
    creator = xml.findall(".//rdau:P60327", namespaces=ns)
    
    try:
        creator = creator[0].text
    except:
        creator = "N/A"
       
        
    meta = {"idn":idn, "creator":creator}
    
    return meta
```

which works wonderfully for all the dc or dcterms elements, also bibo is working fine, but I just cannot get this work for the rdau-elements and I don't understand why. The namespaces are all there, yet when trying to parse the dictionary to a dataframe, I get only "N/A" entries for the rdau-elements. The first bit (idn) works fine, and as I said, I replaces "rdau:P60327" with bibo:isbn13 etc. and then get a result. It's really only the rdau-elements that cause problems.

Does anyone have an idea why this is and how I can solve this?

Comment: It looks like none of the namespaces has a declaration (such as `xmlns:rdf="..."`) in the XML file.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that the namespaces got lost in transition - but they are all there in the data that the function uses, sorry about that. They're all the ones declared in the function. In the meantime, I found out that my problem seems to have something to do with the transition between the data the function uses and the transformed xml with element tree. Not figured out how that helps exactly, though, and still not sure why the current code works for one namespace and not for the other...

Comment: "Got lost in transition" - What transition? Please provide a [mcve], including an XML sample with proper namespace declarations.